# Windows Phone 8 - I have to double tap to load ListBox item to detect tap.

Tags: xaml, listbox, windows-phone-8

Hey guys so I have a page in my Windows phone 8 app and whenever i get to that page, if I click too quickly on any of the ListBox items, it doesn't detect the tap, so I have to re-tap it once or twice more to detect the touch, and sometimes even going back takes more than one tap on the back button(on the phone). Here is the xaml.

```
 <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ListBox x:Name="LocationsList" ItemsSource="{Binding Venues}" toolkit:TurnstileFeatherEffect.FeatheringIndex="2" SelectionChanged="LocationsList_SelectionChanged" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextAccentStyle}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Tap property and a LongListSelector.

```
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"

<phone:LongListSelector Tap="OnSeleted">
```

Not sure about the back key press. Put a breakpoint in a overridden function to make sure it is called each time you press the back key once:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
}
```